# Sinatra - Error Handling

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to make my sinatra app show a custom error page when an error is raised on the server (e.g. an IOError or ArgumentError).

Currently I'm using AJAX to load the results into a certain `#results` div, but if and when an error arises on the server, I would like an error page to open up on a new page.

Currently, the IOError is shown on the server and a error is seen in the console (the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)). Other than that, nothing happens.

I think that I have to play about with the Javascript (as well as the Sinatra::Base class) but I've spent the whole of yesterday and this morning not getting anywhere.

I would be very grateful for any help. I've created an oversimplified version of my app which I have shown below...

**Sinatra_app.rb**

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require9 'sinatra'
require 'slim'

# A helper module
module GVhelpers
  def create_results(name)
    # raise IOError, "There's a problem..."
    return "<p>The Server Says 'Hey #{name}'</p>"
  end
end

class GVapp < Sinatra::Base
  helpers GVhelpers
  set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)

  error do 
    @error = env['sinatra.error']
    slim :"500", :locals => {:error => error}
  end

  get '/' do
    slim :index
  end

  post '/form' do
    name = params[:personName]
    create_results(name)
  end
end

GVapp.run!
```

**index.slim** (in views folder)

```
script src="/jquery.min.js"
script src="/Gvapp.js"

form#sayHey action="/form" method="post"
  |  Name: 
  input type="text" name="personName"
  br
  input type="submit"
#output
```

**500.slim** (in views folder)

```
h1  Oops! Something went Wonky!
p  Apologies, there was an error with your request:
    strong  request.env['sinatra.error'].message
p  If the error persists, please contact the administrator.
```

**Gvapp.js** (in public folder)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#sayHey').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/form',
      data: $('#sayHey').serialize(),
      success: function(response){
        $('#output').html(response);
      }
    })

  })
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sinatra swallows exceptions when run in the `development` environment by default and shows its debugging error page instead. So, to trigger your custom error handlers, you have to either run the application inside a Rack environment other than `development` (probably `production`), or preferably, tell Sinatra to *not* use its default error handlers in `development` mode.

Consider the following, standalone Sinatra application example:

```
require "sinatra"

#disable :show_exceptions

get "/" do
  raise RuntimeError.new("boom")
end

error RuntimeError do
  "A RuntimeError occured"
end
```

If you run this application using the default `development` environment like this:

```
$ ruby foo.rb
```

Then you will get Sinatra’s default error page. If you uncomment the `disable` line in the example, the `error` handler will be triggered instead, displaying a page containing "A RuntimeError occured". Alternatively, you can, as explained, run the application in an environment other than `development` as only that one pre-sets the `show_exception` setting. You can do that by setting the `RACK_ENV` environment variable:

```
$ RACK_ENV=production ruby foo.rb
```

For development purposes, setting `RACK_ENV` to `production` is not the correct way of course. Use `disable :show_exceptions` instead. You can use a `configure` block as [outlined in the Sinatra README](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Configuration) to conditionally disable the setting for the `development` environment.

```
configure :development do
  disable :show_exceptions
end
```

That behaviour is documented in [Sinatra’s documentation on configuration](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html), along with several other useful settings.

Comment: I also had to add an error block to the ajax to catch the error, but thanks a lot, that really helped...

Comment: `dump_errors` is another useful one, which will print the trace to STDERR